# Pseudoinverse code results in C inaccurate compared to MATLAB results

Tags: c, matlab, linear-algebra, svd, matrix-inverse

I am trying to figure out why my pseudoinverse C code results differ from MATLAB results.

This is the code for pseudo-inverse: http://www.mymathlib.com/c_source/matrices/linearsystems/singular_value_decomposition.c

```
#include <string.h>              // required for memcpy()
#include <float.h>               // required for DBL_EPSILON
#include <math.h>                // required for fabs(), sqrt();

#define MAX_ITERATION_COUNT 30   // Maximum number of iterations

//                        Internally Defined Routines 
static void Householders_Reduction_to_Bidiagonal_Form(double* A, int nrows,
    int ncols, double* U, double* V, double* diagonal, double* superdiagonal );
static int  Givens_Reduction_to_Diagonal_Form( int nrows, int ncols,
           double* U, double* V, double* diagonal, double* superdiagonal );
static void Sort_by_Decreasing_Singular_Values(int nrows, int ncols,
                                double* singular_value, double* U, double* V);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  int Singular_Value_Decomposition(double* A, int nrows, int ncols,         //
//        double* U, double* singular_values, double* V, double* dummy_array) //
//                                                                            //
//  Description:                                                              //
//     This routine decomposes an m x n matrix A, with m >= n, into a product //
//     of the three matrices U, D, and V', i.e. A = UDV', where U is an m x n //
//     matrix whose columns are orthogonal, D is a n x n diagonal matrix, and //
//     V is an n x n orthogonal matrix.  V' denotes the transpose of V.  If   //
//     m < n, then the procedure may be used for the matrix A'.  The singular //
//     values of A are the diagonal elements of the diagonal matrix D and     //
//     correspond to the positive square roots of the eigenvalues of the      //
//     matrix A'A.                                                            //
//                                                       

int Singular_Value_Decomposition(double* A, int nrows, int ncols, double* U, 
                      double* singular_values, double* V, double* dummy_array)
{
   Householders_Reduction_to_Bidiagonal_Form( A, nrows, ncols, U, V,
                                                singular_values, dummy_array);

   if (Givens_Reduction_to_Diagonal_Form( nrows, ncols, U, V,
                                singular_values, dummy_array ) < 0) return -1;

   Sort_by_Decreasing_Singular_Values(nrows, ncols, singular_values, U, V);
  
   return 0;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// static void Householders_Reduction_to_Bidiagonal_Form(double* A, int nrows,//
//  int ncols, double* U, double* V, double* diagonal, double* superdiagonal )//
//                                                                            //
//  Description:                                                              //
//     This routine decomposes an m x n matrix A, with m >= n, into a product //
//     of the three matrices U, B, and V', i.e. A = UBV', where U is an m x n //
//     matrix whose columns are orthogonal, B is a n x n bidiagonal matrix,   //
//     and V is an n x n orthogonal matrix.  V' denotes the transpose of V.   //
//     If m < n, then the procedure may be used for the matrix A'.  The       //
//                                                                            //
/
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                            //
static void Householders_Reduction_to_Bidiagonal_Form(double* A, int nrows,
    int ncols, double* U, double* V, double* diagonal, double* superdiagonal )
{
   int i,j,k,ip1;
   double s, s2, si, scale;
   double dum;
   double *pu, *pui, *pv, *pvi;
   double half_norm_squared;

// Copy A to U

   memcpy(U,A, sizeof(double) * nrows * ncols);

//
 
   diagonal[0] = 0.0;
   s = 0.0;
   scale = 0.0;
   for ( i = 0, pui = U, ip1 = 1; i < ncols; pui += ncols, i++, ip1++ ) {
      superdiagonal[i] = scale * s;
//       
//                  Perform Householder transform on columns.
//
//       Calculate the normed squared of the i-th column vector starting at 
//       row i.
//
      for (j = i, pu = pui, scale = 0.0; j < nrows; j++, pu += ncols)
         scale += fabs( *(pu + i) );
       
      if (scale > 0.0) {
         for (j = i, pu = pui, s2 = 0.0; j < nrows; j++, pu += ncols) {
            *(pu + i) /= scale;
            s2 += *(pu + i) * *(pu + i);
         }
//
//    
//       Chose sign of s which maximizes the norm
//  
         s = ( *(pui + i) < 0.0 ) ? sqrt(s2) : -sqrt(s2);
//
//       Calculate -2/u'u
//
         half_norm_squared = *(pui + i) * s - s2;
//
//       Transform remaining columns by the Householder transform.
//
         *(pui + i) -= s;
         
         for (j = ip1; j < ncols; j++) {
            for (k = i, si = 0.0, pu = pui; k < nrows; k++, pu += ncols)
               si += *(pu + i) * *(pu + j);
            si /= half_norm_squared;
            for (k = i, pu = pui; k < nrows; k++, pu += ncols) {
               *(pu + j) += si * *(pu + i);
            }
         }
      }
      for (j = i, pu = pui; j < nrows; j++, pu += ncols) *(pu + i) *= scale;
      diagonal[i] = s * scale;
//       
//                  Perform Householder transform on rows.
//
//       Calculate the normed squared of the i-th row vector starting at 
//       column i.
//
      s = 0.0;
      scale = 0.0;
      if (i >= nrows || i == (ncols - 1) ) continue;
      for (j = ip1; j < ncols; j++) scale += fabs ( *(pui + j) );
      if ( scale > 0.0 ) {
         for (j = ip1, s2 = 0.0; j < ncols; j++) {
            *(pui + j) /= scale;
            s2 += *(pui + j) * *(pui + j);
         }
         s = ( *(pui + ip1) < 0.0 ) ? sqrt(s2) : -sqrt(s2);
//
//       Calculate -2/u'u
//
         half_norm_squared = *(pui + ip1) * s - s2;
//
//       Transform the rows by the Householder transform.
//
         *(pui + ip1) -= s;
         for (k = ip1; k < ncols; k++)
            superdiagonal[k] = *(pui + k) / half_norm_squared;
         if ( i < (nrows - 1) ) {
            for (j = ip1, pu = pui + ncols; j < nrows; j++, pu += ncols) {
               for (k = ip1, si = 0.0; k < ncols; k++) 
                  si += *(pui + k) * *(pu + k);
               for (k = ip1; k < ncols; k++) { 
                  *(pu + k) += si * superdiagonal[k];
               }
            }
         }
         for (k = ip1; k < ncols; k++) *(pui + k) *= scale;
      }
   }

// Update V
   pui = U + ncols * (ncols - 2);
   pvi = V + ncols * (ncols - 1);
   *(pvi + ncols - 1) = 1.0;
   s = superdiagonal[ncols - 1];
   pvi -= ncols;
   for (i = ncols - 2, ip1 = ncols - 1; i >= 0; i--, pui -= ncols,
                                                      pvi -= ncols, ip1-- ) {
      if ( s != 0.0 ) {
         pv = pvi + ncols;
         for (j = ip1; j < ncols; j++, pv += ncols)
            *(pv + i) = ( *(pui + j) / *(pui + ip1) ) / s;
         for (j = ip1; j < ncols; j++) { 
            si = 0.0;
            for (k = ip1, pv = pvi + ncols; k < ncols; k++, pv += ncols)
               si += *(pui + k) * *(pv + j);
            for (k = ip1, pv = pvi + ncols; k < ncols; k++, pv += ncols)
               *(pv + j) += si * *(pv + i);                  
         }
      }
      pv = pvi + ncols;
      for ( j = ip1; j < ncols; j++, pv += ncols ) {
         *(pvi + j) = 0.0;
         *(pv + i) = 0.0;
      }
      *(pvi + i) = 1.0;
      s = superdiagonal[i];
   }

// Update U

   pui = U + ncols * (ncols - 1);
   for (i = ncols - 1, ip1 = ncols; i >= 0; ip1 = i, i--, pui -= ncols ) {
      s = diagonal[i];
      for ( j = ip1; j < ncols; j++) *(pui + j) = 0.0;
      if ( s != 0.0 ) {
         for (j = ip1; j < ncols; j++) { 
            si = 0.0;
            pu = pui + ncols;
            for (k = ip1; k < nrows; k++, pu += ncols)
               si += *(pu + i) * *(pu + j);
            si = (si / *(pui + i) ) / s;
            for (k = i, pu = pui; k < nrows; k++, pu += ncols)
               *(pu + j) += si * *(pu + i);                  
         }
         for (j = i, pu = pui; j < nrows; j++, pu += ncols){
            *(pu + i) /= s;
         }
      }
      else 
         for (j = i, pu = pui; j < nrows; j++, pu += ncols) *(pu + i) = 0.0;
      *(pui + i) += 1.0;
   }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// static int Givens_Reduction_to_Diagonal_Form( int nrows, int ncols,        //
//         double* U, double* V, double* diagonal, double* superdiagonal )    //
//                                                                            //
//  Description:                                                              //
//     This routine decomposes a bidiagonal matrix given by the arrays        //
//     diagonal and superdiagonal into a product of three matrices U1, D and  //
//     V1', the matrix U1 premultiplies U and is returned in U, the matrix    //
//     V1 premultiplies V and is returned in V.  The matrix D is a diagonal   //
//     matrix and replaces the array diagonal.                                //
//                                                                            //
//     The method used to annihilate the offdiagonal elements is a variant    //
//     of the QR transformation.  The method consists of applying Givens      //
//     rotations to the right and the left of the current matrix until        //
//     the new off-diagonal elements are chased out of the matrix.            //
//                                                                            //
//     The process is an iterative process which due to roundoff errors may   //
//     not converge within a predefined number of iterations.  (This should   //
//     be unusual.)                                                           //
//                                                                            //
//  Arguments:                                                                //
//     int nrows                                                              //
//        The number of rows of the matrix U.                                 //
//     int ncols                                                              //
//        The number of columns of the matrix U.                              //
//     double* U                                                              //
//        On input, a pointer to a matrix already initialized to a matrix     //
//        with mutually orthogonal columns.   On output, the matrix with      //
//        mutually orthogonal columns.                                        //
//     double* V                                                              //
//        On input, a pointer to a square matrix with the same number of rows //
//        and columns as the columns of the matrix U, i.e. V[ncols][ncols].   //
//        The matrix V is assumed to be initialized to an orthogonal matrix.  //
//        On output, V is an orthogonal matrix.                               //
//     double* diagonal                                                       //
//        On input, a pointer to an array of dimension ncols which initially  //
//        contains the diagonal of the bidiagonal matrix.  On output, the     //
//        it contains the diagonal of the diagonal matrix.                    //
//     double* superdiagonal                                                  //
//        On input, a pointer to an array of dimension ncols which initially  //
//        the first component is zero and the successive components form the  //
//        superdiagonal of the bidiagonal matrix.                             //
//                                                                            //
//  Return Values:                                                            //
//     0  Success                                                             //
//    -1  Failure - The procedure failed to terminate within                  //
//                  MAX_ITERATION_COUNT iterations.                           //
//                                                                            //
//  Example:                                                                  //
//     #define M                                                              //
//     #define N                                                              //
//     double U[M][N];                                                        //
//     double V[N][N];                                                        //
//     double diagonal[N];                                                    //
//     double superdiagonal[N];                                               //
//     int err;                                                               //
//                                                                            //
//     (your code to initialize the matrices U, V, diagonal, and )            //
//     ( superdiagonal.  - Note this routine is not accessible from outside)  //
//     ( i.e. it is declared static.)                                         //
//                                                                            //
//     err = Givens_Reduction_to_Diagonal_Form( M,N,(double*)U,(double*)V,    //
//                                                 diagonal, superdiagonal ); //
//     if ( err < 0 ) printf("Failed to converge\n");                         //
//     else { ... }                                                           //
//           ...                                                              //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                            //
static int Givens_Reduction_to_Diagonal_Form( int nrows, int ncols,
           double* U, double* V, double* diagonal, double* superdiagonal )
{

   double epsilon;
   double c, s;
   double f,g,h;
   double x,y,z;
   double *pu, *pv;
   int i,j,k,m;
   int rotation_test;
   int iteration_count;
  
   for (i = 0, x = 0.0; i < ncols; i++) {
      y = fabs(diagonal[i]) + fabs(superdiagonal[i]);
      if ( x < y ) x = y;
   }
   epsilon = x * DBL_EPSILON;
   for (k = ncols - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
      iteration_count = 0;
      while(1) {
         rotation_test = 1;
         for (m = k; m >= 0; m--) { 
            if (fabs(superdiagonal[m]) <= epsilon) {rotation_test = 0; break;}
            if (fabs(diagonal[m-1]) <= epsilon) break;
         }
         if (rotation_test) {
            c = 0.0;
            s = 1.0;
            for (i = m; i <= k; i++) {  
               f = s * superdiagonal[i];
               superdiagonal[i] *= c;
               if (fabs(f) <= epsilon) break;
               g = diagonal[i];
               h = sqrt(f*f + g*g);
               diagonal[i] = h;
               c = g / h;
               s = -f / h; 
               for (j = 0, pu = U; j < nrows; j++, pu += ncols) { 
                  y = *(pu + m - 1);
                  z = *(pu + i);
                  *(pu + m - 1 ) = y * c + z * s;
                  *(pu + i) = -y * s + z * c;
               }
            }
         }
         z = diagonal[k];
         if (m == k ) {
            if ( z < 0.0 ) {
               diagonal[k] = -z;
               for ( j = 0, pv = V; j < ncols; j++, pv += ncols) 
                  *(pv + k) = - *(pv + k);
            }
            break;
         }
         else {
            if ( iteration_count >= MAX_ITERATION_COUNT ) return -1;
            iteration_count++;
            x = diagonal[m];
            y = diagonal[k-1];
            g = superdiagonal[k-1];
            h = superdiagonal[k];
            f = ( (y - z) * ( y + z ) + (g - h) * (g + h) )/(2.0 * h * y);
            g = sqrt( f * f + 1.0 );
            if ( f < 0.0 ) g = -g;
            f = ( (x - z) * (x + z) + h * (y / (f + g) - h) ) / x;
// Next QR Transformtion
            c = 1.0;
            s = 1.0;
            for (i = m + 1; i <= k; i++) {
               g = superdiagonal[i];
               y = diagonal[i];
               h = s * g;
               g *= c;
               z = sqrt( f * f + h * h );
               superdiagonal[i-1] = z;
               c = f / z;
               s = h / z;
               f =  x * c + g * s;
               g = -x * s + g * c;
               h = y * s;
               y *= c;
               for (j = 0, pv = V; j < ncols; j++, pv += ncols) {
                  x = *(pv + i - 1);
                  z = *(pv + i);
                  *(pv + i - 1) = x * c + z * s;
                  *(pv + i) = -x * s + z * c;
               }
               z = sqrt( f * f + h * h );
               diagonal[i - 1] = z;
               if (z != 0.0) {
                  c = f / z;
                  s = h / z;
               } 
               f = c * g + s * y;
               x = -s * g + c * y;
               for (j = 0, pu = U; j < nrows; j++, pu += ncols) {
                  y = *(pu + i - 1);
                  z = *(pu + i);
                  *(pu + i - 1) = c * y + s * z;
                  *(pu + i) = -s * y + c * z;
               }
            }
            superdiagonal[m] = 0.0;
            superdiagonal[k] = f;
            diagonal[k] = x;
         }
      } 
   }
   return 0;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// static void Sort_by_Decreasing_Singular_Values(int nrows, int ncols,       //
//                            double* singular_values, double* U, double* V)  //
//                                                                            //
//  Description:                                                              //
//     This routine sorts the singular values from largest to smallest        //
//     singular value and interchanges the columns of U and the columns of V  //
//     whenever a swap is made.  I.e. if the i-th singular value is swapped   //
//     with the j-th singular value, then the i-th and j-th columns of U are  //
//     interchanged and the i-th and j-th columns of V are interchanged.      //
//                                                                            //
//  Arguments:                                                                //
//     int nrows                                                              //
//        The number of rows of the matrix U.                                 //
//     int ncols                                                              //
//        The number of columns of the matrix U.                              //
//     double* singular_values                                                //
//        On input, a pointer to the array of singular values.  On output, the//
//        sorted array of singular values.                                    //
//     double* U                                                              //
//        On input, a pointer to a matrix already initialized to a matrix     //
//        with mutually orthogonal columns.  On output, the matrix with       //
//        mutually orthogonal possibly permuted columns.                      //
//     double* V                                                              //
//        On input, a pointer to a square matrix with the same number of rows //
//        and columns as the columns of the matrix U, i.e. V[ncols][ncols].   //
//        The matrix V is assumed to be initialized to an orthogonal matrix.  //
//        On output, V is an orthogonal matrix with possibly permuted columns.//
//                                                                            //
//  Return Values:                                                            //
//        The function is of type void.                                       //
//                                                                            //
//  Example:                                                                  //
//     #define M                                                              //
//     #define N                                                              //
//     double U[M][N];                                                        //
//     double V[N][N];                                                        //
//     double diagonal[N];                                                    //
//                                                                            //
//     (your code to initialize the matrices U, V, and diagonal. )            //
//     ( - Note this routine is not accessible from outside)                  //
//     ( i.e. it is declared static.)                                         //
//                                                                            //
//     Sort_by_Decreasing_Singular_Values(nrows, ncols, singular_values,      //
//                                                 (double*) U, (double*) V); //
//           ...                                                              //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                            //
static void Sort_by_Decreasing_Singular_Values(int nrows, int ncols,
                                double* singular_values, double* U, double* V)
{
   int i,j,max_index;
   double temp;
   double *p1, *p2;

   for (i = 0; i < ncols - 1; i++) {
      max_index = i;
      for (j = i + 1; j < ncols; j++)
         if (singular_values[j] > singular_values[max_index] ) 
            max_index = j;
      if (max_index == i) continue;
      temp = singular_values[i];
      singular_values[i] = singular_values[max_index];
      singular_values[max_index] = temp;
      p1 = U + max_index;
      p2 = U + i;
      for (j = 0; j < nrows; j++, p1 += ncols, p2 += ncols) {
         temp = *p1;
         *p1 = *p2;
         *p2 = temp;
      } 
      p1 = V + max_index;
      p2 = V + i;
      for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++, p1 += ncols, p2 += ncols) {
         temp = *p1;
         *p1 = *p2;
         *p2 = temp;
      }
   } 
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  void Singular_Value_Decomposition_Inverse(double* U, double* D, double* V,//
//                     double tolerance, int nrows, int ncols, double *Astar) //
//                                                                            //
//  Description:                                                              //
//     This routine calculates the pseudo-inverse of the matrix A = UDV'.     //
//     where U, D, V constitute the singular value decomposition of A.        //
//     Let Astar be the pseudo-inverse then Astar = V(1/D)U', where 1/D is    //
//     the pseudo-inverse of D, i.e. if D[i] > 0 then (1/D)[i] = 1/D[i] and   //
//     if D[i] = 0, then (1/D)[i] = 0.  Because the singular values are       //
//     subject to round-off error.  A tolerance is given so that if           //
//     D[i] < tolerance, D[i] is treated as if it were 0.                     //
//     The default tolerance is D[0] * DBL_EPSILON * ncols, assuming that the //
//     diagonal matrix of singular values is sorted from largest to smallest, //
//     if the user specified tolerance is less than the default tolerance,    //
//     then the default tolerance is used.                                    //
//                                                                            //
//  Arguments:                                                                //
//     double* U                                                              //
//        A matrix with mutually orthonormal columns.                         //
//     double* D                                                              //
//        A diagonal matrix with decreasing non-negative diagonal elements.   //
//        i.e. D[i] > D[j] if i < j and D[i] >= 0 for all i.                  //
//     double* V                                                              //
//        An orthogonal matrix.                                               //
//     double tolerance                                                       //
//        An lower bound for non-zero singular values (provided tolerance >   //
//        ncols * DBL_EPSILON * D[0]).                                        //
//     int nrows                                                              //
//        The number of rows of the matrix U and B.                           //
//     int ncols                                                              //
//        The number of columns of the matrix U.  Also the number of rows and //
//        columns of the matrices D and V.                                    //
//     double* Astar                                                          //
//        On input, a pointer to the first element of an ncols x nrows matrix.//
//        On output, the pseudo-inverse of UDV'.                              //
//                                                                            //
//  Return Values:                                                            //
//        The function is of type void.                                       //
//                                                                            //
//  Example:                                                                  //
//     #define M                                                              //
//     #define N                                                              //
//     double U[M][N];                                                        //
//     double V[N][N];                                                        //
//     double D[N];                                                           //
//     double Astar[N][M];                                                    //
//     double tolerance;                                                      //
//                                                                            //
//     (your code to initialize the matrices U,D,V)                           //
//                                                                            //
//     Singular_Value_Decomposition_Inverse((double*) U, D, (double*) V,      //
//                                        tolerance, M, N, (double*) Astar);  //
//                                                                            //
//     printf(" The pseudo-inverse of A = UDV' is \n");                       //
//           ...                                                              //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                            //

void Singular_Value_Decomposition_Inverse(double* U, double* D, double* V,  
                        double tolerance, int nrows, int ncols, double *Astar) 
{
   int i,j,k;
   double *pu, *pv, *pa;
   double dum;

   dum = DBL_EPSILON * D[0] * (double) ncols;
   if (tolerance < dum) tolerance = dum;
   for ( i = 0, pv = V, pa = Astar; i < ncols; i++, pv += ncols) 
      for ( j = 0, pu = U; j < nrows; j++, pa++) 
        for (k = 0, *pa = 0.0; k < ncols; k++, pu++)
           if (D[k] > tolerance) *pa += *(pv + k) * *pu / D[k];
}
```

I have set my tolerance to 1e-16.

Input Matrix:

```
MatA[4][4] = {
                    {1e-15,2e-15,3e-15,4e-15},
                    {5e-15,10e-15,7e-15,8e-15},
                    {9e-15, 18e-15, 11e-15,12e-15},
                    {13e-15,26e-15,15e-15,16e-15}
                    };
```

C code results:

```
-7.3177e+13 -3.6957e+13 -7.3773e+11 3.5482e+13
-1.4635e+14 -7.3915e+13 -1.4755e+12 7.0964e+13
1.0264e+14 5.7015e+13 1.1387e+13 -3.4240e+13
1.9055e+14 1.0400e+14 1.7450e+13 -6.9101e+13
```

Matlab results:

```
   1.0e+14 *

   -0.7348   -0.3712   -0.0076    0.3561
   -1.4697   -0.7424   -0.0152    0.7121
    1.0227    0.5682    0.1136   -0.3409
    1.9015    1.0379    0.1742   -0.6894
```

I am not sure where I am losing accuracy. The only place I can see accuracy to come into effect is DBL_Epsilon and Tolerance. I have also put the value for DBL_Epsilon as 4.94065645841247E-32. Not sure how I would get closer values to the matlab output.

Comment: Please don't post links to the code. Include the code within the post itself.

Comment: ... and the code should be presented in the post as a [mre] - so not a dump of **all** your code, but _just enough_ so it's **possible to compile** it and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Note that you could avoid the `e-15` in the input matrix (and just multiply by `e15` the result) , even if in practice it should not change too much the issue. An interesting test would be the check the singular values of the input matrix, with both codes.

Comment: Hmm I won't have the character space to post the code and how I am calling the pseudoinverse function. But I am simply calling Singular_Value_Decomposition(double* A, int nrows, int ncols, double* U, double* singular_values, double* V, double* dummy_array) then Singular_Value_Decomposition_Inverse(double* U, double* D, double* V,  double tolerance, int nrows, int ncols, double *Astar)

Comment: This is quite a lot of code to go through. I suspect the discrepancy you see is going to be due to how small singular values are dealt with. You can see exactly what Matlab does by opening the `pinv` function, which should help you debug.

Comment: You're basically trying to pinv(zeros(4)) which doesn't make much sense to me. Matlab is using the LAPACK library for its behind-the-scenes linear algebra calculations. However, LAPACK does not have a pinv equivalent function. As mentioned, comparing your posted code and Matlab's pinv function, there exists a slight difference that could justify a discrepancy for such small values. We cannot play around with other values since you haven't provided the exact code you're working with. Your tol value is also inherently odd, almost working against the algorithm -trying to keep everything nonzero.

Comment: I've fixed your MATLAB results, they are 10 orders of magnitude larger than you suggested. And they are very similar to the ones you get in C. The number with the largest relative difference is 2.6% off. This is not bad, considering that the input matrix has rank 2.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ah thank you, that was a typo. Yup I'm wondering why this 2.6% error even occurs considering both methods are using SVD to find the pseudoinverse.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely your choice of tolerance. MATLAB sets the tolerance by default to `max(size(A)) * eps(norm(A))` (according to [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html#d123e1043422)). For your matrix, this is 2.5244e-29.

If I compute `A*pinv(A)*A - A` I see

```
   1.0e-28 *

   -0.0039   -0.0079         0         0
   -0.0237   -0.0473   -0.0158         0
   -0.0473   -0.0947   -0.0316         0
   -0.0789   -0.1578   -0.0316   -0.0316
```

If I compute the same but using your result instead of `pinv(A)`, I see

```
   1.0e-16 *

   -0.0430   -0.0860    0.0582    0.1088
   -0.1356   -0.2712    0.1862    0.3472
   -0.2282   -0.4565    0.3143    0.5855
   -0.3209   -0.6417    0.4423    0.8239
```

Looking at these magnitudes, this really points to the two choices for tolerance.

Comment: So you gave the value for double tolerance as (max(size(A)) * eps(norm(A)))? In other words I would have to calculate norm for each A matrix to get the most accurate results? Isn't that what    dum = DBL_EPSILON * D[0] * (double) ncols is doing in the pseudoinverse function

Comment: @CodingCurry `DBL_EPSILON * D[0]` is not the same as `eps(norm(A))`, though if the elements of your matrix all have a similar magnitude, then it might not make a difference. I'm just telling you what the MATLAB documentation says that `pinv` does.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I am now running into the problem where if I have small numbers within a diagonal: {1.2993813e-05 ,399.24500 ,44.210205 ,-12.781491},
{-399.24490 ,-2.8729439e-05 ,-14.342758 ,0.95198631},
{-44.210159 ,14.342835 ,1.7166138e-05 ,-164.82639},
{12.781399 ,-0.95199490 ,164.82642 ,0}
} The pinv matrix result has the correct values for all the elements except for the ones on the diagonal. Is this also due to tolerance?